# Not able to run discovery in XenApp 6.5

Tags: xenapp

I am installing a fresh Citrix farm. I installed XenApp 6.5 and configured while configuring the XenApp, added domain\ctxadmin user as the farm administrator. Now when i log into Administrator account into the XenApp server and run discovery it says

This user account is not an administrator of this farm, or there was a problem contacting the data store. Check that the data store server for the Citrix XenApp farm is online, and verify that your account is configured and enabled as an administrator on the farm

Then I tried to RDP into the XenApp server as ctxadmin user and now I get an error

"The Desktop you are trying to open is currently unavailable. Contact you system administrator to confirm the correct settings are in place for your client connection"

I believe starting from XenApp version 6.x, once XenApp is installed, then a Citrix Policy needs to be changed as given in http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX124745

But for changing the Citrix policy I need to log into AppCenter which I am not able to do so as I am not able to run discovery as given above. So I am caught up in an end-less loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This happens as the current desktop on which you are running App center is not the administrator on Xenapp. Please try invoking App Center from the server itself while logging on to it as domain\ctxadmin (as this is the admin account). You can then add any other account as Citrix administrators on the app center.

Once other accounts are added, you can run the app center from any other desktop logged in with the new accounts.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to run the command on xenapp server
Qfarm /load.. 
If yes, then you have admin privileges. If not, then you might need to look at admin rights on farm